# Get status of a process started by Invoke-WmiMethod

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, win32-process

New to PowerShell, but loving the fact that I can do so much so quickly so far :)

Anyways, I am starting a remote process in a PowerShell script thusly:

```
$compname = "MY-PC"
$myinstallcmd = "c:\install\myprog.exe /s"
$proc = Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_Process -name Create -ArgumentList ($myinstallcmd) -ComputerName $compname
```

On most of the PCs I've tried, the Invoke-WmiMethod cmdlet works fine, but on one PC, it's hanging. What I'm now looking to do is get the status of the running process, and if it's hung up, kill it and log the kill, and then move on.

I did find a possible method to do this in the post 
[Starting a process remotely in Powershell, getting %ERRORLEVEL% in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299720/starting-a-process-remotely-in-powershell-getting-errorlevel-in-windows) - however, when I try to do the Register-WmiEvent on the process $proc.ProcessId, I'm getting the dreaded `0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)` error... I am running the PowerShell host as domain admin.

Can anyone please suggest a way that I can get a status on the process I've started, and be able to take an action based on the status?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I guess you are missing remote system credentials:

Try passing the credentials to remote system using `-Credential` parameter. This takes a PSCredential Object and hence you can do something like:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Register-WMIEvent -Credential $cred <and other parameters here>
```

See if any of the following resolves the access denied error:

0x80070005 (DCOM ACCESS_DENIED) 
This error occurs when the connected user is not recognized or is restricted in some fashion by the remote server (for example, the user might be locked out). This happens most often when accounts are in different domains. Recent changes to WMI security can also cause this error to occur:

- Blank passwords, formerly permitted, are not allowed in Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.
- WMI does not allow asynchronous callbacks to a Windows 98 client. A call like SWbemServices.ExecNotificationQueryAsync from a Windows 98 computer to a Windows XP computer will result in an Access Denied error returned to the Windows 98 machine.
- The DCOM configuration access setting might have been changed.
- If the target computer is running Windows XP, the Forceguest value under the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa might be set to force the Guest account off (value is zero).

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx

Comment: Add'l info: Powershell host on system running Win7, target machine running Win Vista. Have `powershell_ise` process running as a Domain Admin acct. `Register-WmiEvent` does not have `-Authentication` or `-Impersonation` param's like `Get-WmiObject` does, which I have used before when I have gotten this sort of error...

Comment: You can use -Credential parameter provide credentials

Comment: So here's what I just tried now: `$proc2 = Invoke-WmiMethod -AsJob -class Win32_Process -name Create -ArgumentList ($installcmd) -ComputerName $compname -Authentication 6 -Credential $cred Register-WmiEvent -ComputerName $compname -Query "Select * from Win32_ProcessStopTrace Where ProcessID=$($proc2.ProcessId)" -Action { Write-Host "Process ExitCode: $($event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.ExitStatus)" } -Credential $cred` -- I still am getting the error `Register-WmiEvent : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`

Comment: Also I should mention that I did set the `$cred` variable via `Get-Credential` and used a Domain Admin account